# Precise factorization of Dedekind zeta function of cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K=\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/m})$ be a cyclotomic field.
I have frequently seen the assertion that its Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ factors into Dirichlet $L$-functions:
$$
\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\chi\pmod m} L(s,\chi).
$$
However, in Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, Proposition 5.12 states instead that
$$
\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\mathfrak p\mid m} (1-\mathfrak N(\mathfrak p)^{-s})^{-1} \prod_{\chi\pmod m} L(s,\chi).
$$
I'm confused by this apparent discrepancy and could use some remedial help. So:

- Does $L(s,\chi)$ refer to a possibly imprimitive character $\chi\pmod m$, or to a primitive character modulo a divisor of $m$?
- Are the factors for $\mathfrak p\mid m$ present in the formula or not?
- If they are present, can one evaluate them in terms of $m$ alone and not the arithmetic of $K$?
- Is there one precise and clear statement that would serve as a suitable reference for me to cite?

Comment: In the first formula, your first bullet applies: those $L(s,\chi)$ are for the $\chi$s that are primitive for factors of $m$. In the second formula, they are not, they are all Dirichlet characters modulo $m$, primitive and imprimitive. Because of this, the Euler factors for $p\mid m$ have to be re-inserted.

Comment: That is $\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\chi\in Hom(\Bbb{Z/mZ}^\times,\Bbb{C})} L(s,\tilde{\chi})$ with $\tilde{\chi}$ is the primitive Dirichlet character inducing $\chi$ @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: I want to find the number of ideals of fixed norm, say $c_p$ for some prime $p$ for a cyclotomic field. To find $c_p$, I thought that  we must find $\displaystyle\sum_{\text{all characters } \chi \\ d | p , a_1 \dots a_{\phi(m)}=d} \chi(a_1)\dots\chi(a_{\phi(m)})$. However, I only get $1$ in each case because I sum over all characters. What is my mistake and how can I find the value of $a_p$ exactly?